# how to rectify the error Attempt to execute SCRIPT mat2cell as a function?

Tags: matlab

On doing image processing, I tried to do split an image into blocks. For that I used the function `mat2cell`. But I got an error

> Attempt to execute SCRIPT mat2cell as a function:

Please help me to rectify this error.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have an .m file `mat2cell.m` in your path, which is overriding the builtin [Matlab function mat2cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html).

If you're not aware of this script in your path, write `mat2cell` in the command window, select it, right click, and click on `Open Selection`. That will bring you to the overriding .m file.

Always be careful not to write scripts that override builtin functions.

Comment: Or use the `which` command.